# Random freezing on ESXi environment across several servers

Tags: windows-7, memory, esxi, windbg

Over the past couple of weeks we've been experiencing some issues with our ESXi based VDI environment whereby Windows 7 Desktop images randomly freeze throughout the day.

This can happen on any VDI Win7 image on any one of our ESXi hosts and as far as we are aware no changes to the system or software have been made recently (hmmm...).

If I look at the console of a frozen system it's not always entirely frozen. Sometimes I can send it a ctrl+alt+del signal and it will do something, but not always. Furthermore, the CPU usage for the VM in ESXi is actually quite low (<5% usage) so it doesn't seem to be a run-away process dragging it down.

In an attempt to diagnose the issue I took a snapshot of a couple of the VM's while frozen and converted their vmss's to dmp files. I then loaded them into windbg and was given the following info:

```
0: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

NMI_HARDWARE_FAILURE (80)
This is typically due to a hardware malfunction.  The hardware supplier should
be called.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000004f4454
Arg2: 0000000000000000
Arg3: 0000000000000000
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x80

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80001886113 to fffff80001e0d0ba

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff800`0169aad0 fffff800`01886113 : 00000000`00000000 fffff800`01e293c0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalpRtcClockInterrupt+0x2a
fffff800`0169ab00 fffff880`033cd9c2 : fffff800`01892709 00000000`00369e99 fffffa80`0249d638 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiInterruptDispatchNoLock+0x163
fffff800`0169ac98 fffff800`01892709 : 00000000`00369e99 fffffa80`0249d638 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : intelppm!C1Halt+0x2
fffff800`0169aca0 fffff800`0188189c : fffff800`01a04e80 fffff800`00000000 00000000`00000000 fffff880`0105e800 : nt!PoIdle+0x52a
fffff800`0169ad80 00000000`00000000 : fffff800`0169b000 fffff800`01695000 fffff800`0169ad40 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x2c


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!KiInterruptDispatchNoLock+163
fffff800`01886113 f685f3000000ff  test    byte ptr [rbp+0F3h],0FFh

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!KiInterruptDispatchNoLock+163

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  521ea035

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x80_nt!KiInterruptDispatchNoLock+163

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x80_nt!KiInterruptDispatchNoLock+163

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

and this...

```
1: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

NMI_HARDWARE_FAILURE (80)
This is typically due to a hardware malfunction.  The hardware supplier should
be called.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000004f4454
Arg2: 0000000000000000
Arg3: 0000000000000000
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x80

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80001892709 to fffff880033cd9c2

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`009fbc98 fffff800`01892709 : 00000000`00369e99 fffffa80`0249b598 fffff880`009f2f40 00000000`00000001 : intelppm!C1Halt+0x2
fffff880`009fbca0 fffff800`0188189c : fffff880`009e8180 fffff880`00000000 00000000`00000000 fffff800`01941430 : nt!PoIdle+0x52a
fffff880`009fbd80 00000000`00000000 : fffff880`009fc000 fffff880`009f6000 fffff880`009fbd40 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x2c


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
intelppm!C1Halt+2
fffff880`033cd9c2 c3              ret

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  intelppm!C1Halt+2

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: intelppm

IMAGE_NAME:  intelppm.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4a5bc0fd

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x80_intelppm!C1Halt+2

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x80_intelppm!C1Halt+2

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Although it is suggesting a hardware issue (as far as I can tell), I find this hard to believe as we have several different farms with varying hardware and it is occurring on all of them.

Is there anything I can do to troubleshoot this further? My experience of windbg is very basic.

Comment: At a guess - all Intel CPU's, right?  From what little I can gather, the Host machines CPUs are entering power save for some reason.  The Intel C1Halt is part of the CPUs power saving mode - which should be bios disabled on vm hosts

Comment: I'm pretty sure all of this is already disabled. SOme of our servers have been running for best part of a year without any issues and all of a sudden this freezing has started occurring.

I've checked the timestamps of any files mentioned in the memory dumps, and none have been updated recently either. SO I'm lost :(

Comment: Did you ever sort this? We are having the EXACT same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into an issue with 2008 servers freezing randomly, obtained a dmp file from the vmss files and saw exactly the same output. I drilled down into the dmp file and traced the final memory locations to some sort of system level api indicating that an interrupt concerning the processors had been received but hadn't completed.

I confidently stated to my bosses that this meant a hardware error, despite several hosts in two data centres being involved. After all, with a hypervisor being involved abstracting from the hardware itself there might be an interrupt being triggered somewhere that didn't come from the hardware itself.

Then I had a horrible thought, and fired up a working vm in workstation, suspended it, got a dmp file and ran that in windbg. Guess what - exactly the same output.

I believe the nmi shown is a result of the suspend process itself. You can get other useful stuff out of windbg - memory allocation etc -  but please don't waste your time trying to track down an nmi issue.